# Existence of the Periodic Solution on a Nonlinear Differential Equation

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems, periodic-functions

I have a TR (research work) concerning the equation: $$x '(t) + g (x (t)) = f (t),\quad \forall t\in \mathbb R$$
f and g are defined and continuous in $\mathbb R$ and with values ​​in $\mathbb R$.
Furthermore f is assumed to be T periodic (There is no initial condition)

**First question:**

Assume that there is a periodic solution. Using the mean formula,  to show that $\frac 1T \int_0 ^ T f (t) dt \in g (\mathbb R) $

**Second question**

what to add as hypotheses  for the existence of a periodic solution

***For first question:***

$ g \circ x $ being continuous, there is a $ c $
between $ 0 $ and $ T $ such as $ \frac 1T\int_0 ^ T
 g (x (s)) ds = g (x (c)) $. So if $ x $ is a solution
$ T $ periodic, because $ x (T) = x (0) $, we
will have:

$$\frac1T \int_0 ^ T f (s) ds = \frac 1T \int_0 ^ T
 (g (x (s)) + x '(s)) ds = \frac1T \int_0 ^ T
 g (x (s)) ds = g (x (c)) \in g (\mathbb R). $$

***For second question:***

I need help  what to add as hypotheses?